# Web3 is injecting but stilling getting an invalid provider error

Tags: web3js, metamask, react

I'm injecting web3 with MetaMask, and everything works, but when I make a production build, I notice that it injects web3 alright, but when I try to call a web3 function, it throws `Please provide an valid Web3 provider'; specifically the error is being thrown when I try to make a contact instance.

Here's my code

```
if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  console.log("Using web3 detected from external source like Metamask");
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  window.alert("No web3 detected. This site is a Web3 Dapp - to proceed you will need to get Metamask https://metamask.io/");
}

...

this.contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address)
```

When I run the development build, everything works fine. But when I make a production build using `npm react-scripts build` and run it, then I get an error.

Edit:
Here is the error logged in the console
[image]

Comment: Since last year Metamask recommends a different way to inject web3 in your app https://metamask.github.io/metamask-docs/API_Reference/Ethereum_Provider

Comment: provide error log if possible.

Comment: It seems like my problem was with how react-scripts was creating the production build or with the project dependencies. I changed some things around and it's working now.